# How do I insert into a table and get back the primary key value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a primary key set up to auto increment.

I am doing multiple queries and I need to retrieve that primary key value to use as a foreign key in another table (`IsIdentity = TRUE`).

Is there any elegant way to get back the primary key value when I do an insert query?  Right now I am requerying and getting the highest value in that column which seems really hacky.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
insert into YourTable values (...)
```

get the new PK with scope_identity()

```
select scope_identity()
```

Comment: +1 yup, using scope_identity() is the most reliable and efficient way to go!

Comment: NOt the best method anymore.

Comment: Use the Output clause

Comment: Does `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` work when used in JDBC batches?

Answer (score 43):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use the OUTPUT clause.

```
create table T(
  pk int identity primary key,
  dat varchar(20)
);
go

insert into T
output inserted.pk
values ('new item');
go

drop table T;
```

The output can be directed to a table as well as to the client. For example:

```
create table T(
  pk int identity primary key,
  dat varchar(20)
);

create table U(
  i int identity(1001,1) primary key,
  T_pk int not null,
  d datetime
);
go


insert into T
output inserted.pk, getdate()
into U(T_pk,d)
values ('new item'), ('newer item');
go

select * from T;
select * from U;
go

drop table T, U;
```

Beginning with SQL Server 2008, you can use "composable DML" for more possibilities.

Comment: +1 another very good approach, which also works if the PK isn't an identity - good callè

Comment: It's also a single statement rather than 2 which could be useful

Comment: Even better if you have multiple records in an insert you can get all the ids as well as the natural key.

Comment: The limitation here is that if the table you're inserting has triggers enabled, then you must use the `into` clause which makes this a whole lot more clunky than `scope_identity` for single records

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 12):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (1, 2, etc.)
OUTPUT inserted.yourIDcolumn
VALUES (value1, value2, value...)
```

Note: This is for MS SQL 2005 and greater

Answer (score 5):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() is probably what you want.  It returns the ID of the last record inserted by the same code context in which it executes.

IDENT_CURRENT('tablename') is subject to concurrency issues.  That is, there's no guarantee that another record won't be inserted between the INSERT and the call to IDENT_CURRENT.

I must confess, I'm not sure to what source of amazement the VillageIdiot's outburst refers, but I myself am quite astonished that this question does not appear to be a duplicate at all.

Comment: glad its not flagged as a dup, I found it first!!

Answer (score 3):

holy crap!!!

just call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function:

```
insert into your_talble(col1,col2) values('blah','more blah')
select scope_identity()
```

because selecting highest value will return error if any other statement make an insert. the function `scope_identity()` returns the identity created in current context (that is by your statement)

Answer (score 2):

You should use scope_identity(). And I recommend to wrap insert statement and scope_identity() into transaction.