# Use auto increased ID as the filename

Tags: sql, sql-server

File Table

```
Id,   RealName, FilePathName
1000, foo.doc,  C:\data\1000
```

The SQL is something like,

```
INSERT INTO [File] ([RealName], [FilePathName])
VALUES ('foo.doc', 'C:\data\'+(CAST Inserted.Id AS VARCHAR))
```

Reg. `Inserted.Id`, it's the PK of the just inserted data entry. People can get the PK with `output Inserted.Id`
[How do I insert into a table and get back the primary key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360453/how-do-i-insert-into-a-table-and-get-back-the-primary-key-value)
But can't use it as a parameter.

Sometimes though the file name won't include the PK so it has to be stored explicitly.

Is there any way to insert the field value with the just created PK?

Comment: You can do it with a `SEQUENCE` object, but not with `IDENTITY` - unless you make it a two-step operation: `INSERT` with a dummy filename, then `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and then use that to `UPDATE SET Name = `.

Comment: If the prefix is static, you can use a calculated column `FilePathName AS 'C:\data\' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(6))` . Or you can store the root path in the table and use a calculated column for the full path : `FilePathName AS RootPath + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(6))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did consider a computed column too, but I fear that leaves very little room for flexibility later on. If SQL allowed a DEFAULT constraint to use another column, I would have suggested that, but perhaps a good solution for this is a trigger to change that value on insert.

Comment: You can add the root as a column

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I got you. seems I actually don't have to store the dummy filename at all. But maybe sometimes the dummy file name would not be the PK. So I'd better record it.

Comment: In that case it's better to use a SEQUENCE instead of IDENTITY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to add a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to update the table when you insert new rows. This has the benefit that you always have the default value of `c:\data\<id>` but allows you to change it later if you need a different file name. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateFilePathName ON [File]
AFTER INSERT
AS

UPDATE [File]
SET [FilePathName] = 'C:\data\' + CAST([File].ID AS varchar(20))
FROM [File]
INNER JOIN inserted ON inserted.ID = [File].ID
```

Note: There are usually other considerations to take into account when using triggers, but this might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you can tolerate using two separate transactions, you could do the insert, followed by an update:

```sql
INSERT INTO [File] ([RealName])
VALUES ('foo.doc');

UPDATE [File]
SET [FilePathName] = 'C:\data' + (CAST Id AS VARCHAR(20));
```

Comment: Or use a computed column